# Spring static resource mapping does not work

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

i am trying to create a Spring MVC application with security included. All configuration is made in code, no XML-s. First, i have my  WebApplicationInitializer, mapping all requests to my dispatchservlet:

```
public class DBCAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(DBCConfiguration.class);
    ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet(
            "dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    servlet.addMapping("/"); 
    servlet.setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement("", 1024*1024*5, 1024*1024*5*5, 1024*1024));


}
```

Also there is a config file:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "our.dbc")
public class DBCConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DBCConfiguration.class);

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolverJsp(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    viewResolver.setOrder(0);
    log.info("####   Internal view resolver 0 called...");
    return viewResolver;
}

@Bean
public StandardServletMultipartResolver multipartResolver(){
    log.info("####   Multipart resolver called...");
    return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
}

//    @Override 
//    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)  {
//       registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
//          .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
//        
//    }
//    
//    @Override
//    public void   configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
//       configurer.enable();
//    }
}
```

As you can see, i have tried both addResourceHandler and configureDefaultServletHandling, but none of those worked. Problem is that all request by default, with lowest priority end up returing welcome page (so if bad address requested, welcome is returned :), so that instead of getting the css client gets back to welcome page:

```
@Controller
public class FileUploadController {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(FileUploadController.class);

private static final String FORM = "form";

private static final String WELCOME = "welcome";

private static final String DENIED = "accessDenied";

private static final String UPLOADED_REDIRECT = "redirect:/uploaded";

@Autowired
FileUploadService uploadService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getWelcome() {
     return WELCOME;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginPage() {
    LOG.info("####   /login called..." );
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value = { "/uploaded" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getUploaded() {
    LOG.info("####   /uploaded called..." );
    return "uploaded";
}
.
.
.
```

As i said, i also have security configured, but with default container servlet serving static resources, it whould not have to be changed. Anyway, i tried also to add permitall to resources, but no success. Anyway if i disable security it does not work either, so security is not the problem.

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

  http.authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/welcome").permitAll() 
    .antMatchers("/form").access("hasRole('ADMIN')and hasRole('USER')")
.
.
.
```

But no chances. If i type http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/resources/app.css instead of getting the stylesheet, browser gets back to welcome page.

Any suggestions? Any help whould be appreciated :)

Comment: `/**` is a catch all... So anything will endup in there unless it is explicitly mapped.

Comment: But shouldnt this instruct tomcat to use its default servlet handler to handle static resource?`@Override
    public void   configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
       configurer.enable();
    }` _This allows for mapping the DispatcherServlet to "/" (thus overriding the mapping of the container’s default Servlet), while still allowing static resource requests to be handled by the container’s default Servlet._

Comment: No as that will only work if there is nothing that will catch the url... Your `/**` catches everything, so the request is never passed on to the servlet container. So yes it should handle that, but it doesn't because you have a catch all url.

Comment: So if i want to catch all non-existing page requests, and redirect to some site (in this case to WELCOME), but exclude static resources i whould have to do something like `@RequestMapping(value = { "/{^(resources)}**", "/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)` (this actually works!)? This is the only solution? Thanks.